# Getting information from mysql using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have mysql database for i fetch information using json
for example:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM parent WHERE id = '$name'";       
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
$abc=$row[id];
}
echo json_encode($abc)
```

Now how can i display this json encoded element in my main html file using jquery?
what i want to do is based on this fetched element i want to do some if else operation.

for example:

```
if(value of row[id](should be achieved using jquery) ==null)
{}
else
{}
```

I am looking for something like $(xxxx).somefunction()
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to convert the [JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) into a JavaScript object and then add the properties  of the object into your html.

```
jQuery.parseJSON( json )
```

Add the JSON from the database to your webpage through:

```
echo "var myJson = ".json_encode($abc);
```

Then use jQuery to parse the JSON through:

```
myObject = jQuery.parseJSON(myJson);
alert(myObject.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a javascript var:

```
echo('var test = ' . json_encode($abc));
```

Now you can acces the var "test" with javascript.

Comment: hey i am looking for something like this $(xxxx).somefunction()